# Converting dates in msg file to match outlook local dates muddle

Tags: time, timezone, aspose, msg

I am taking the MSG file and changing the date to match the local date in outlook. (same Sent date when you open the message in outlook).
But the times seem to be off 1 hour or many hours.  I've dumped out the times to investigate further:-
I'm using Aspose to open the msg file.
c#

1.msg Shows: 05/01/2011 00:46 in outlook 2016. GMT

05/01/2011 00:46:07, Kind = Utc
TimeZone offset = -08:00:00
Actual UTC Time is  05/01/2011 00:46:07
Message date to universal time + timezoneoffset: 04/01/2011 16:46:07
timezoneoffset: -08:00:00
calculated universal msg date: 04/01/2011 16:46:07
output 04/01/2011 08:46 AM

2.msg Shows 20/06/2016 16:25 in outlook 2016. GMT

20/06/2016 16:25:23, Kind = Local
TimeZone offset = 02:00:00
Actual UTC Time is  20/06/2016 15:25:23
Message date to universal time + timezoneoffset: 20/06/2016 17:25:23
timezoneoffset: 02:00:00
calculated universal msg date: 20/06/2016 17:25:23
output 06/20/2016 07:25 PM

any ideas on how to correct this to show same as outlook? I see some times are UTC and some are Local, is there a solution anyone know of?

```
MailMessage msg = MailMessage.Load(inFile);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

Console.WriteLine(msg.Date.ToString() + ", Kind = " + msg.Date.Kind);

Console.WriteLine("TimeZone offset = " + msg.TimeZoneOffset);
Console.WriteLine("Actual UTC Time is  " + msg.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Message date to universal time + timezoneoffset: " + (msg.Date.ToUniversalTime() + 
msg.TimeZoneOffset).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("timezoneoffset: " + msg.TimeZoneOffset.ToString());

// do calculation.
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
TimeSpan ts = localZone.GetUtcOffset(msg.Date);
msg.Date = msg.Date + msg.TimeZoneOffset;

Console.WriteLine("calculated universal msg date: " +msg.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString());


if (msg.Date.Second >= 30) // for rounding up to match outlook
{
// ... Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 31, 0);
msg.Date = msg.Date + span;
}

MhtMessageFormatter mhtlFormat = new MhtMessageFormatter();
mhtlFormat.DateTimeFormat = "ddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt";
mhtlFormat.Format(msg);
MhtSaveOptions mhtSaveOptions = new MhtSaveOptions();
mhtSaveOptions.MhtFormatOptions = MhtFormatOptions.None;
mhtSaveOptions.MhtFormatOptions = mhtSaveOptions.MhtFormatOptions |     MhtFormatOptions.HideExtraPrintHeader;
```

Thanks,
Lee.

Answer (score 0):

As assisted on your [thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/723631/742973/showthread.aspx#742973) in Aspose.Email forum, we believe your query has already met an answer. If you still find any issue or have confusion, you can inquire further on respective thread.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.